# How to verify a failed scenario in After method i'm using Nightwatch API (formerly Night-Cucumber). To Update browserstack rest API (pass/fail)

Tags: nightwatch.js, cucumberjs, browserstack

I am using Nightwatch API(formerly Nightwatch-Cucumber) in browserstack. I am unable to find a code to update the status of Rest Api (passed/failed) in browserstack by verifying failed scenarios in my test. I need to use this in my After method.
thanks in advance.
I wanted to use similar one as below code in Cucumber.conf.js file

afterTest: test => {
   if (!test.passed) {
request({uri: `https://${user}:${key}@api.browserstack.com/app- automate/sessions/${browser.sessionId}.json`,
        method:'PUT',
        form:{ 'status':'error','reason': errors.join(' | ') },
    })
}

Answer (score 0):

You should have below library in the script: 
var request = require("request");

You can use the following code: 
request({uri: "https://:@api.browserstack.com/automate/sessions/.json", method:"PUT", form:{"status":"passed","reason":""}})

You can refer the sample code from the below link: 
https://www.browserstack.com/automate/node#rest-api

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply.  When i use the above request  it simply displays as pass in browerstack regardless of status of my test. I am looking for a code where i can verify the status of my scenario pass or fail. And i can use the code you send to display the result in browserstack.